# How PrefetchCount and ConcurrentMessageLimit influence restarting receiveEndpoint after KillSwitch

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, messaging, masstransit

I'm configuring a KillSwitch. It doesn't restart endpoints (resume consuming) sometimes. I don't fully understand how values set in ConcurrentMessageLimit and PrefetchCount influence Restart capability.

Restarting Receive Endpoints works correctly when:

1. ConcurrentMessageLimit and PrefetchCount are not set.
2. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1, PrefetchCount = 1
3. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1, PrefetchCount = 2

Restarts don't work at all when:

1. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1, PrefetchCount not set

Restarts only once or not at all:

1. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 5, PrefetchCount = 25

Stop doesn't work (I can see in the logs that Threshold is reached, but the endpoint didn't stop completely, still is Healthy, but I would expect Degraded)

1. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1, PrefetchCount = 4
2. ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1, PrefetchCount = 5

Behaviors in the above examples also sometimes differ when I provide 100% faulted incoming messages and when ~30%.

**Looks like ConcurrentMessageLimit = 1 and PrefetchCount = 1 is a safe setting as it works quite nicely and stable. But why? I'd like to understand those behaviors.**

Below is my ConfigureConsumer method from ConsumerDefinition class.

```
protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<Consumer<TInMessage, TProcessable>> consumerConfigurator)
  {
    endpointConfigurator.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
    endpointConfigurator.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();

    consumerConfigurator.UseConcurrentMessageLimit(1);
    //endpointConfigurator.PrefetchCount = 1;

    endpointConfigurator.UseKillSwitch(options => options
      .SetActivationThreshold(3)
      .SetTripThreshold(0.1)
      .SetRestartTimeout(m: 1)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `UseConcurrentMessageLimit(1);` is deprecated, you should simply set `ConcurrentMessageLimit` on the receive endpoint configurator.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work correctly. Can I find info about deprecation somewhere in the docs? The method itself isn't marked as Obsolete. How should I know that this method is deprecated and shouldn't be used?

Comment: The documentation is currently being re-platformed/rewritten, but you can [view the receive endpoint documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#receive-endpoints) for details.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson  Post your solution as an answer so that it can help other community members with the same type of issue.